# How to make scatter plots similar to the one in the paper "Get me off Your F****** Mailing List"?

Tags: python, r, plot, scatter-plot

*This is a serious question. Please do not take it as a joke.*

This is a scatter plot from an infamous paper with the same name, [Get me off Your F****** Mailing List](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/%7Edm/home/papers/remove.pdf) by Mazières and Kohle (2005), published in a predatory journal. Some people may know it.

[image]

I am seriously interested in recreating the same scatter plot to test a new *density-based clustering algorithm* without the need of creating all the letters from scratch.

Is there any way to make this process easier? (e.g. a dataset, or a package, or a smart way to recreate the plot)

Comment: You could start a predatory journal!

Comment: This might be useful: https://www.autodesk.com/research/publications/same-stats-different-graphs

Comment: Or it would probably be easier to create an image file with the text you want to produce on a white background, then read that image file and check the color of each pixel. Then you can generate a bunch of random points and only keep them for positions where the pixel is not white. This sample image looks like they used clipping paths to mask points rather than actually generating data to match the letter shape (not all plotting characters seem to be fully visible)

Comment: @MrFlick One idea is to create the letters, then adding Gaussian random noises to each point. However, it is not aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the suggestion. It is actually a good one that I have not thought of.

Comment: I'm guessing the graph was created by randomly sampling 2D points and then rejecting all that don't fall within the font outlines. However, this is only a guess since the author didn't publish their detailed methods (at least I can't find them in the published paper). Shoddy publishing standards. Anyway, there are several packages that help you get the outline of text, e.g. [‘string2path’](https://cran.r-project.org/package=string2path) and [‘fontr’](https://github.com/yixuan/fontr).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that the grid package supports clipping paths, we can do:

```r
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

tg <- textGrob("Get me off\nYour Fuck\ning Mailing\nList", x = 0.2,
               hjust = 0,
               gp = gpar(cex = 6, col = "grey", font = 2))
cg <- pointsGrob(x= runif(15000), y = runif(15000), pch = 3,
                 gp = gpar(cex = 0.5))

rg <- rectGrob(width = unit(0.5, 'npc'), height = unit(0.1, 'npc'),
               gp = gpar(fill = 'red'))

ggplot(data = NULL, aes(x = 100, y = 100)) +
  geom_point(col = 'white') +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = 'white', linewidth = 1))

pushViewport(viewport(clip = tg))
grid.draw(cg)
```

[image]

Comment: It indeed looks like the original version. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Pikachu피카츄 But note that this just masks the points drawn on the image. It doesn't subset the points in any way that you can use for clustering algorithms. It's a purely visual effect.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to actually generate random points sampled from within text, you could do this using Python's Numpy and Pillow modules relatively easily.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

lines = ["Get me off", "your Fuck", "ing Mailing", "List"]

# get a nice heavy font
font = ImageFont.truetype("fonts/Lato-Black.ttf", size=200)

# calculate width
width = max(font.getbbox(line)[2] for line in lines)

# create BW image containing text
im = Image.new('1', (width, len(lines) * font.size))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    draw.text((0, i * font.size), line, font=font, fill=1)

# sample points
y, x = np.where(np.array(im) > 0)
ii = np.random.randint(len(x), size=sum(map(len, lines)) * 50)
x = x[ii] / im.width
y = y[ii] / im.height

# recreate figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.semilogy()
ax.scatter(x, 10**(y*-5), 7**2, linewidths=0.5, marker='+', color='black')
ax.set_xlabel("Your Fucking Mailing List")
ax.set_ylabel("Get me off")
ax.set_title("Get me off Your Fucking Mailing List")
```

which might produce something like:

[image: resulting matplotlib output]

The lack of masking makes it more difficult to see the letters, but given you seemed to want points for clustering this might not matter so much.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. Your program produced random points which actually are what I need. I already accepted the answer above, so I can't accept this one.

Comment: no probs, I mostly answer questions here to understand libraries better

Answer (score 1):

Using matplotlib and clipping, this doesn't (unfortunately) handle multi-lines easily:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.textpath import TextPath
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from matplotlib.transforms import IdentityTransform

import numpy as np

ax = plt.subplot()

N = 7000
x = np.random.random(size=N)
y = np.random.random(size=N)


ax.scatter(x, y, marker='+', color='k', lw=0.5)
text = 'StackOverflow'

text = TextPath((60, 200), text,
                prop=FontProperties(weight='bold', size=55),
                )

ax.collections[0].set_clip_path(text, transform=IdentityTransform())
```

Output:

[image]